# How do i put a sprite on an android XML layout file?

Tags: android, sprite

I don't have any code in my frogger.xml file, and i need to get a picture of a frog at the bottom of the scereen, and be able to put the code for it in a different folder. How would i do this? (simply,  please, I'm a beginner)

also, i am using eclipse and android 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremely vague. But okay.

To put an image at the bottom of your screen, make your frogger.xml say this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/frog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where `android:src="@drawable/frog"` is pulling in the image of your frog (if its frog.png or something) from the res>drawable folder.

If you're planning on doing graphics and making a frogger game, you really need to look into other things first.

Comment: can you elaborate on "other things"?

Comment: If you don't know how to put an image in an xml file you're definitely a real beginner. You don't just jump in and make a game. You'll need to learn the basics of layouts and intents and stuff, and then you have to get into graphics. Check out this post: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/how-do-i-get-started-making-android-games

Comment: i can put an image in an XML file, i just don't know how to use it as a sprite.

Comment: Okay, then check this out: http://www.droidnova.com/2d-sprite-animation-in-android,471.html